# How to avoid `for` loops for indexing for huge data

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

This is my code. I would like to avoid `for` loop for huge number of iterations.

```
iterations = 10000
max_number = 9700
W = is a matrix(300,9700)

def grad_function(x,y):
    grad = np.sum(W*(x - y))
    return grad

x = np.arange(300)
y = np.arange(9700)

for i in range (iterations):
    for j in range(max_number):
        result = grad_function(x,y)
print(result)
```

I tried using the `map()` function instead but it does not give me a result including 9700 elements; instead, it gives me a list of 300 elements which is not correct.

Comment: Maybe if you show *how* you "used map()", someone could help you fix it.

Comment: Why are you running the same function 97000000 times and only using last result?

Comment: Normally when we iterate, we use `i,j` as arguments, not the `x,y`.  Your loop as written is doing the same thing over and over.  Skip the loop and call the `grad_function` just once.

Comment: Replacing your nested `for` requires nested `map`.  I think you need to practice with simpler basic python loops.  You don't seem to understand the basics.  But as I wrote above, if `grad_function` works with the whole `x` and `y`, there's no need to iterate at all.

Comment: ty for your replies. I used the map() and it worked but still not fast at all! because in every iteration needs to calculate grad_func for 9700 values; even in first iteration took a few minutes!

you are right I am using the last result here sorry :)) it is because I just simplified my code here so I missed the part where I stored 9700 values in a vector and then update them again in each iteration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I understand a `map()` does essentially the same as your nested `for`-loops and if you need to check every value in the matrix, this will be one of the fastest options anyway.

Comment: It's true that `map()` will be faster than looping, though probably not as fast as a list comprehension. But NumPy ufuncs are faster.

Comment: Ok why would map be faster, it essentially does the same thing, it goes trow every value one after the another

Comment: `map()` is lazy, for one thing, but in general map and list comprehensions don't create a list and keep appending to it. That's what kills the for loop (not that OP is appending, but they meant to with this approach).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do something like this:

```py
W = np.random.random((300, 9700))
x = np.arange(300)
y = np.arange(9700)

result = (W.T @ x) - y
```

Then `result.shape` is `(9700,)`. Alternatively, you can make `W` have shape `(9700, 300)` and then you won't need to transpose it.

In general, you never need to loop with NumPy. Just do the maths on the arrays directly. The only trick I've used here is `@` instead of `np.matmul`.

If you really want to use a function for the maths, be sure to pass in everything it needs:

```py
def grad(x, y, W):
    return (W.T @ x) - y
```